# CSS3 not cross-browser rendering

Tags: css, gradient

I have CSS3 gradients and CSS3 background-clip, but Firefox, Safari and IE don't render them. This is my code:

I tried with pogid filters for IE, but nothing.

Thanks!

```
 background: linear-gradient(top, #b58600 0%, #ffbd00 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-            stop(0%,#b58600), color-stop(100%,#ffbbd00)); 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b58600 0%, #ffbd00 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b58600 0%, #ffbd00 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b58600 0%, #ffbd00 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b58600 0%, #ffbd00 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b58600', endColorstr='#ffbd00',GradientType=0 );
 background-clip: text;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -moz-background-clip: text;
 -o-background-clip: text;
 -ms-background-clip: text;
 -khtml-background-clip: text;
```

Comment: I feel there is an issue with the background-clip, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Also change the `color` property to `transparent`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E22wh/